# How to select such instances from pandas series of strings which are having a given substring present?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to figure out such instances from a `pandas series` of strings that are having a specific substring. For eg: In the below `dataframe`,

[image: Dataframe]

I want to know which instances in `car_data` are having `Cr` as a substring present in `car_data['New_Price']`. (some eg. value are `18.65 Lakh`,`NaN`,`1.28 Cr`).(I want to know more about instances having `1.28 Cr` as `car_data['New_Price']`)

I have tried the below code :

```
instances=car_data['New_Price']
for instance in instances:
    if('Cr' in instance):
        car_data.loc[instance]
```

But it gives me the error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
F:\Users\lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2656             try:
-> 2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2658             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type()

KeyError: '1.28 Cr'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-265-ec5cde3ce12d> in <module>
      2 for instance in instances:
      3     if('Cr' in instance):
----> 4         car_data.loc[instance]

F:\Users\lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1498 
   1499             maybe_callable = com.apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
-> 1500             return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
   1501 
   1502     def _is_scalar_access(self, key):

F:\Users\lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _getitem_axis(self, key, axis)
   1911         # fall thru to straight lookup
   1912         self._validate_key(key, axis)
-> 1913         return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)
   1914 
   1915 

F:\Users\lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _get_label(self, label, axis)
    139             raise IndexingError('no slices here, handle elsewhere')
    140 
--> 141         return self.obj._xs(label, axis=axis)
    142 
    143     def _get_loc(self, key, axis=None):

F:\Users\lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in xs(self, key, axis, level, drop_level)
   3583                                                       drop_level=drop_level)
   3584         else:
-> 3585             loc = self.index.get_loc(key)
   3586 
   3587             if isinstance(loc, np.ndarray):

F:\Users\lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2658             except KeyError:
-> 2659                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2660         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2661         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type()

KeyError: '1.28 Cr'
```

Can you please help me a bit. I'm in desperate need.

Comment: Try: `car_data[car_data['New_Price'].str.contains('Cr')]`

Comment: @Erfan thanks a lot sir for your help. Thanks again for your support.